# Problem comprehending an equation about Stopping Times

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stopping-times, filtrations

I am given the following definition:

T is a stopping time if $\{T⩽t\}∈F_t$ for all t. $\{S∧T⩽t\}=\{S⩽t\}∪\{T⩽t\}$ both of which are in $F_t$.

I do not understand the $\cup$ sign.

In my logic (which seems wrong), I would follow that the $\cup$ should be a $\cap$ sign. 
I want that both T and S are $\leq$ t (that is what the $\land$ sign means to me), so I would assume I have to intersect the respective sets (Would my logic at least be right for 'standard' logical sets?).

I guess it has something to do with the filtration $F_t$ but I'm at a total loss here, please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equality rests on the fact that for $u,v\in\mathbb R$, 
$$
\min\{u,v\}\leqslant t\Leftrightarrow \left(\left(u\leqslant t\right)\mbox{ or }\left(v\leqslant t\right)\right).
$$
Similarly, 
$$
\max\{u,v\}\leqslant t\Leftrightarrow \left(\left(u\leqslant t\right)\mbox{ and }\left(v\leqslant t\right)\right).
$$

Comment: So  $\{S∧T⩽t\}$ means $min\{S,T\} \leq t$ ?

Comment: @Alex Exactly. ${}{}$

Comment: Does the symbol $\land$ always stand for the minimum (and vice versa $\lor$ for the maximum (what is the logic behind that?))?

Comment: It's a common notation in this kind of context.

Comment: Thank you a lot for your answers.

Comment: In stochastic processes there is often (e.g. in the definition of the stochastic integral) the same symbol(s) in the index of some integrands (e.g. in equation (1) in https://almostsure.wordpress.com/2010/01/03/the-stochastic-integral/#scn_int_def4 ), does this also take on the meaning of the minimum of t and $t_k $ / $s_k$ ?